# Referencing the ContentManager in a static class? (C#, XNA)

Tags: c#, xna, sprite

I have created a static class which needs to be able to change the sprite used in an object. However, in non-static classes, I was able to refer to the ContentManager in the object as `this.Content`, but in a static class, it says "this" cannot be used.

Im a bit lost as to how to reference the content manager in this object from the static class. I tried using the object instead of `this` (`enemies[i].`), but this didnt work. I also tried using just `ContentManager.`, but it tells me that doesnt exist as well.

I still dont fully understand the ContentManager and why it needs to be in each object, but I've had a hard time finding really detailed information about what it is and what it does (most tutorials seem to gloss over it, just saying that its necessary)

Heres a snippet of the code I have so far. Its simplified a bit (a lot more goes on), but only the `this.Content` part is giving me trouble:

```
public static void fight(List<enemy> enemies)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Count; i++)
            {
                if (enemies[i].hp <= 0)
                                {
                                    enemies[i].LoadContent(this.Content, "spr_enemy_dead");
                                }
```

This is the method that contains the content manager inside the `enemy` object:

```
public void LoadContent(ContentManager theContentManager, string AssetName)
    {
        spr_enemy = theContentManager.Load<Texture2D>(AssetName);
    }
```

There is probably a better way to do this, but I havent found anything in my searching.

Comment: You keep talking about "the object" - *which* object? A static method has no context... do you understand the difference between static and instance methods? (If you're new to C#, I would *strongly* recommend that you learn the language via simple console apps etc before you embark on XNA.)

Comment: Well, that's a bit harsh, but true. You could try passing your ContentManager to the fight method as a parameter, but you really shouldn't do that. :)

Comment: Sorry, the list (List<enemy> enemies) is a list of objects that i pass into this method. I meant to include that but forgot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ContentManager is static, probably declared like this:

```
class YourObject
{
    static public ContentManager Content;
```

You are already within a static function of this object, so you can simply access it like this:

```
enemies[i].LoadContent(Content, ...
```

or:

```
enemies[i].LoadContent(YourObject.Content, ...
```

If your Content object is not declared statically, you can't access it within a static call unless you have a reference on YourObject...